# php regex finding nested patterns

Tags: php, regex

I try to read foreach loops from a html file. For example:

```
{foreach $foo as $bar}
      {$bar->getName()}
{endforeach}

// but also nested loops
{foreach $foo as $bar}
      {foreach $bar as $b}
           {$b->getName()}
      {endforeach}
{endforeach}

 // with regex
 preg_match_all('/{foreach(.*?)}(.){endforeach}/us',$html, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER
```

The tried my best on this great regex101.com site here... [see example](https://regex101.com/r/V75R1k/3)
At least I get two matches in this example.
Although I would like the nested part also.
But when I use this regex in my php app it returns an empty array.
As soon as I use the dot `(.)` only in second group nothing ever gets returned unlike on regex101.com

Could that be a php7 problem ? Please help

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a [recursive regex](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-recursion.html). How about something like this pattern (without flags) [`/{(foreach)[^}]*}(?>[^{]+|{(?!(?:end)?\1)|(?R))*{end\1}/`](https://www.regex101.com/r/EWgJUy/1)

Comment: but that doesn't give me the inner loop either.

Comment: Thanks anyway ..... But I realized that this is the wrong approach. I dont need them in a nested order. Now I get all with `/{((\w+)(.*?))}` and then do all the str replacements to get the valid php strings.

Comment: maybe you can optimize it a bit like this: [`/{(\w+)[\s.]*([^}]*)}/`](https://www.regex101.com/r/EWgJUy/2)

Answer (score 0):

did you already tried something similar:

```js
function parseForeach(s) {
  let [, varName, arrayName, body] = (/(?:{foreach\s?(\$\w+)\s+(?:as)\s+(\$\w+)})\s+{(.*)}\s+(?:{endforeach})/g.exec(s) || []);
  ;
  
  console.log({varName, arrayName, body});
}


var tpl = `
{foreach $foo as $bar}
      {$bar->getName()}
{endforeach}

// but also nested loops
{foreach $foo as $bar}
      {foreach $bar as $b}
           {$b->getName()}
      {endforeach}
{endforeach}
`;


parseForeach(tpl);
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized that this is the wrong approach. I dont need them in a nested order. Now I get all with `/{((\w+)(.*?))}` and then do all the str replacements to get the valid php strings.
                    – FitzPatrick